# How to create a dropdown control dynamically using jquery and asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

So i have a very little challenge. In the Database, i'm retrieving a a value for each user(Note: the values are not the same). For example, user A might have value 2, while User B might have user 3. What i want to do is create a dropdown corresponding to the value of each user. So if user B logs in, three dropdown will be displayed while if its user A, two dropdown will be displayed. I want to create this dropdown dynamically. Ho do i achieve this using Jquery ?

Comment: you could use `AJAX` to get how many dropdown should be shown based on the user, then fetch each of its value into dropdownlist

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the challenge is, i'm not quite familiar with AJAX. I have to implementt it because that's what the project requires. Any link you can point me to or an article i could read to do this?

Comment: or you could use `binding` from the server side